# Is there any way to safely upgrade a Google Cloud Platform VPC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc

Is there a practice to update google cloud platform VPC?

Comment: What is update/upgrade here? Moving up to higher tier? The VM OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practice to update VPC in Google cloud. The Google Cloud Platform VPC is automatically updated by Google and you can check the release notes [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/release-notes). With regards to the effects on your project you can also check that in the release notes page.

If you are referring to updating a specific function on VPC like adding a new region, please elaborate.

Comment: Thank you, this is the kind of answer I am looking for. 

Currently, I am wondering why there is no practice to upgrade a cloud VPC. As whenever I want to do something, I tend to think about the maintainability part, whether I should create 2 VPC in the same region or similar things.

From your answer, it is clear now